# Symfony2 + Twig get real/full current route

Tags: symfony, twig, routes

I have a routing with optional parameters:

```
/**
  * @Route( "/route/{id}", name="_route", defaults={"id" = ""} )
  * @Template()
  */
```

In the template I have a form and I want the form to be send to either:

```
/route
```

or:

```
/route/10
/route/10/mail – if there were more than just one parameter
```

At the moment I'm solving it like this:

```
{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route')) }}/{{ object.id }}
```

Which works fine, but I have to add all possible parameters by myself. Is there a way to get the full current path from within twig? I don't want to add an extra variable in my controller to be send to the template.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `Request` class has a [`getRequestUri()`](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/Request.php#L715) method. You can access it in twig like

```
{{ app.request.requesturi }}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is one more way (not sure whether it is a good practice or not):

```
{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')) }}
```

And in this case you can add an additional parameter to it:

```
{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')|merge({'p': 10})) }}
```

Comment: It should be noted that this will not include query parameters that are not part of the defined route.

Comment: @ChadwickMeyer well, in my example `p` may be a part of a route. Or it may not be. Anyway, it will be still used. However, if you want to include the arguments passed using a query string, you can use `app.request.query` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Are different actions. Different actions that have different templates. With twig you can have 2 or 3 templates that extends a third one. In third one you can define the bloc of the list. And a blok of the form. In twig you can extends templates.

I still, ... think you need different templates and different actions. Each action's template,  extends a "super" template with the list.

Comment: I definitely get your point here and now I put all things into different actions and recall them when needed. But it's still good to know, how to get the full route within twig. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use multiple @Route in you action:

```
/**
  * @Route( "/route/{id}", name="_route" )
  * @Route( "/route/{id}/hello", name="_route_hello" )
  * @Route( "/route/{id}/hello/{world}", name="_route_hello_world" )
  * @Template()
  */
```

And check if a variable exists ...

But ... I do not understand you need to use same action with different route. I prefer use one action for each "purpose". And to follow DRY pattern, I like to write some private method for not rewrite code ...

Comment: My basic problem is: I call a form, if no param is given, a new object is created, otherwise the current one (loaded by id) will be updated. After saving, the object should be displayed again. But with this **{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route')) }}** he sends the form back to **"route"** no matter there is an id involved or not. This is what I'm trying to do. Hope, you understand. Maybe I'm thinking to complicated here.

Comment: I still see different behaviors. I do not understand why you want do 3 things in the same place.

Comment: So the idea is: we want to list entries on the left side. When you click on a entry, it's selected and you can edit it on the right side.  But the list is still visible. If no entry is selected you can simply create a new one with the empty form on the right side.